# Can't seem to get my && operation running

Tags: android

I have a very simple code here that i'm trying to create on android studio but it can't seem to work out.

the code are as follow

```
if (Username = "sharesharerocks" && PassWord = "shareshare") {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not about your && ,

you just mistake the comparing operator

change it to

```
if(Username == "sharesharerocks" && PassWord == "shareshare"){

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, just starting out programming kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are doing java and want to compare strings. The appropriate thing would be

```
 if(Username.equals("sharesharerocks") && PassWord.equals("shareshare")){}
```

Better yet, use StringUtils to handle case where your Username/PassWord is null

```
if(StringUtils.equals(Username,"sharesharerocks") && StringUtils.equals(PassWord,"shareshare")){}
```

Comment: no need for StringUtlis with at least one literal `"literal".equals(variable_which_can_be_null);`